# Jenkins/Hudson is not catching Perl script errors

Tags: perl, error-handling, hudson, jenkins

I am currently triggering Perl scripts using Jenkins/Hudson, however, I am struggling to find out what the proper exception is to throw some Jenkins picks it up. In the console it shows that the perl script errors like it's suppose to, but Jenkins finishes with Build Success.

I have tried numerous things from the die command and a system print of exit 1 and it still doesn't appear to be catching any of it.

Any help would be great! Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins considers a build step that exits with non-zero to have failed. It should be enough to `die()`

Maybe you have another shell command after perl which exits with zero? Jenkins does not see every exit code from the individual processes. Jenkins simply places the script you enter into the build step area into a temporary file and calls `/bin/sh` on the temp file. It is up to you to make the script exit with non-zero when the script fails.

The easiest way to do it is to begin your script with `#!/bin/sh -xe`. If you study the shell man page, you will see the `-e` option makes shell stop the script whenever any process exits with non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this while running a Jenkins job on Linux versus Windows. I learned (the hard way) that Linux return codes must be between 0 and 255. If the return code is outside of this range, the return code will be set to 0. The Perl documentation states that the return code of die() is non-zero, but is not anymore specific.
Therefore, if your die() call generates a non-zero return code that is not between 0 and 255, Linux will treat it as zero.

Answer (score 0):

I used [TAP::Harness::JUnit](https://metacpan.org/module/TAP%3a%3aHarness%3a%3aJUnit). It would make wrap the TAP output in an XML document and then the XML would be delivered vi SCP to the Hudson server for Hudson to Consume.

It took a little wrangling to get the hudson command to do all the shell commands properly but by that I mean two or three tries to get all the paths set correctly.